# ethereum fastvsyncing is never finish (geth)

Tags: geth

I have run geth --fast --cache=4000 for 8 days and I think I am almost complete:

```
eth.syncing {   
currentBlock: 8123223,   
highestBlock: 8123315,   
knownStates: 309587058,   
pulledStates: 309573531,   
startingBlock:    > 8123170 
}
```

geth is import state entries only.

my timedatectl output is:

```
                      Local time: Wed 2019-07-10 11:49:05 UTC
                  Universal time: Wed 2019-07-10 11:49:05 UTC
                        RTC time: Wed 2019-07-10 11:49:06
                       Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

it is finish sync after 10 days.(2 core cpu, 4gb ram)

Comment: jeez 10 days is a lot.. thanks for sharing, at least others can see a light at the end of tunnel

Comment: It takes me 10 days and still syncing on 6 core 16GB RAM, I used fast sync also, don't know how to complete sync as soon as possible, still syncing: ``` > eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 12302109,
  highestBlock: 12302213,
  knownStates: 165715671,
  pulledStates: 165617068,
  startingBlock: 12285779
}```